# Переписать с JS на PHP

Tags: php

Всем привет, пишу скрипт грамматически правильного деления слова на слоги. Столкнулся с проблемой, подскажите пожалуйста, как переписать этот JS код на PHP?

```js
var vowel = new String('аеёиоуыэюя'); // Гласные буквы
var voiced = new String('бвгджзлмнрхцчшщ'); // Звонкие и шипящие согласные
var deaf = new String('кпстф'); // Глухие согласные
var brief = new String('й'); // Й
var other = new String('ьъ'); // Другие
var cons = new String('бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщ'); // Все согласные
// Валидация правильности введенной строки
function validateString(s) {
  // Поленился делать :)
  return s;
} // function validateString (s)
// Есть ли в строке гласные?
function isNotLastSep(remainStr) {
  var is = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < remainStr.length; i++) {
    if (vowel.indexOf(remainStr.substr(i, 1)) != -1) {
      is = true;
      break;
    }
  } // for (var i = 0; i < remainStr - 1; i++)
  return is;
} // function isLastSep (remainStr)
// Собственно функция разбиения слова на слоги
function getSeparatedString(s) {
  // Добавляем слог в массив и начинаем новый слог
  function addSep() {
    sepArr.push(tmpS);
    tmpS = '';
  } // function addSep ()
  s = validateString(s);
  var tmpL = new String(); // Текущий символ
  var tmpS = new String(); // Текущий слог
  var sepArr = new Array(); // Массив слогов
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    tmpL = s.substr(i, 1);
    tmpS += tmpL;
    // Проверка на признаки конца слогов
    // если буква равна 'й' и она не первая и не последняя и это не последний слог
    if (
      (i != 0) &&
      (i != s.length - 1) &&
      (brief.indexOf(tmpL) != -1) &&
      (isNotLastSep(s.substr(i + 1, s.length - i + 1)))
    ) {
      addSep();
      continue;
    }
    // если текущая гласная и следующая тоже гласная
    if (
      (i < s.length - 1) &&
      (vowel.indexOf(tmpL) != -1) &&
      (vowel.indexOf(s.substr(i + 1, 1)) != -1)
    ) {
      addSep();
      continue;
    }
    // если текущая гласная, следующая согласная, а после неё гласная
    if (
      (i < s.length - 2) &&
      (vowel.indexOf(tmpL) != -1) &&
      (cons.indexOf(s.substr(i + 1, 1)) != -1) &&
      (vowel.indexOf(s.substr(i + 2, 1)) != -1)
    ) {
      addSep();
      continue;
    }
    // если текущая гласная, следующая глухая согласная, а после согласная и это не последний слог
    if (
      (i < s.length - 2) &&
      (vowel.indexOf(tmpL) != -1) &&
      (deaf.indexOf(s.substr(i + 1, 1)) != -1) &&
      (cons.indexOf(s.substr(i + 2, 1)) != -1) &&
      (isNotLastSep(s.substr(i + 1, s.length - i + 1)))
    ) {
      addSep();
      continue;
    }
    // если текущая звонкая или шипящая согласная, перед ней гласная, следующая не гласная и не другая, и это не последний слог
    if (
      (i > 0) &&
      (i < s.length - 1) &&
      (voiced.indexOf(tmpL) != -1) &&
      (vowel.indexOf(s.substr(i - 1, 1)) != -1) &&
      (vowel.indexOf(s.substr(i + 1, 1)) == -1) &&
      (other.indexOf(s.substr(i + 1, 1)) == -1) &&
      (isNotLastSep(s.substr(i + 1, s.length - i + 1)))
    ) {
      addSep();
      continue;
    }
    // если текущая другая, а следующая не гласная если это первый слог
    if (
      (i < s.length - 1) &&
      (other.indexOf(tmpL) != -1) &&
      ((vowel.indexOf(s.substr(i + 1, 1)) == -1) ||
        (isNotLastSep(s.substr(0, i))))
    ) {
      addSep();
      continue;
    }
  } // for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
  sepArr.push(tmpS);
  return sepArr.join('-');
} // function getSeparatedString (s)
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" size="30" name="fromString" value="">
  <input type="button" value="Go!" onClick="document.forms[0].elements[2].value = getSeparatedString (document.forms[0].elements[0].value);">
  <br>
  <input type="text" size="30" name="toString" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: Так с какой проблемой столкнулись-то?

Comment: Недостаточно навыков

Comment: Недостаточно навыков для идентификации проблемы? Или вы хотите чтобы вот прям всё за вас сделали? Код на js-то хоть корректный?

Comment: За навыками - в учебники